# Django matching query does not exist - about encoding

Tags: django, unicode

I've got a Error: "User does not exist" when I'm querying in Django by Chinese name of users.
related codes:

```
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

user_name = sheet.cell_value(r, 7).replace(' ', '')
equipment.eq_receiver = User.objects.get(user_name=user_name)

class User(AbstractUser):
    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
  response = get_response(request)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
  response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
  response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
  return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "F:/repositories/ITIMS\eqp_mgt\views.py", line 652, in import_excel
  equipment.eq_receiver = User.objects.get(user_name=user_name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
  return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 380, in get
  self.model._meta.object_name
DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.
```

In Debugger,I got the value of *user_name*:

`user_name={unicode}u"邵阳"`

Then in *Watches* view of Pycharm,I tried some other queries,but the result confused me:

```
User.objects.get(user_name=u'\u90b5\u9633')={User}邵阳  #unicode of '邵阳'
User.objects.get(user_name=u'邵阳')={DoesNotExist}User matching query does not exist.
User.objects.get(user_name='邵阳')={User}邵阳
User.objects.get(user_name=user_name)={DoesNotExist}User matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are using python 2.7 instead of 3? Python 3 makes working with international characters much easier.

Comment: @Ire I'm modifying a previous system coded with python 2.7.13 so I don't prefer to python 3.

Comment: check your database encodings...

Comment: I've finally found the reason why this error happened,the value from excel contains zero-width-joiner:*\u200d*.Thanks for your suggestion.